# How to integrate Gimbal with Vuforia android application?

Tags: android, geolocation, augmented-reality, vuforia, gimbal

I checked with gimbal.com official site. They haven't provided any samples which can integrate with vuforia SDK.

Please suggest me where I can find the integration samples?